# Angular 4 RC.4 & .net core The selector "app" did not match any elements

Tags: webpack, asp.net-core, angular

I have this https://github.com/damirkusar/AngularMeetsNetCore/tree/AngularRc4 project where I use Angular 4 RC.4 and .net core. When updating a file and the app refreshes through hot module replacement, i get the following error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: The selector "app" did not match any elements ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: ZoneAwareError__zone_symbol__error: Error: The selector "app" did not match any elements
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:24029:19) [angular]
    at DebugRenderer2.selectRootElement (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:12878:49) [angular]
    at createElement (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:9171:23) [angular]
    at createViewNodes (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:11672:44) [angular]
    at createRootView (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:11619:5) [angular]
    at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:12727:42) [angular]
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:12204:12) [angular]
    at ComponentFactory_.create (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:9591:46) [angular]
    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:3490:29) [angular]
    at ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:5024:57) [angular]
    at http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:4811:79 [angular]
    at Array.forEach (native) [angular]
    at PlatformRef_._moduleDoBootstrap (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:4811:42) [angular]
    at http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:4772:27 [angular]__zone_symbol__message: "The selector "app" did not match any elements"__zone_symbol__stack: "Error: The selector "app" did not match any elements↵    at DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:24029:19) [angular]↵    at DebugRenderer2.selectRootElement (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:12878:49) [angular]↵    at createElement (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:9171:23) [angular]↵    at createViewNodes (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:11672:44) [angular]↵    at createRootView (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:11619:5) [angular]↵    at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:12727:42) [angular]↵    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:12204:12) [angular]↵    at ComponentFactory_.create (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:9591:46) [angular]↵    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:3490:29) [angular]↵    at ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:5024:57) [angular]↵    at http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:4811:79 [angular]↵    at Array.forEach (native) [angular]↵    at PlatformRef_._moduleDoBootstrap (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:4811:42) [angular]↵    at http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:4772:27 [angular]"message: (...)name: (...)ngDebugContext: DebugContext_ngErrorLogger: ()originalStack: (...)stack: (...)toSource: ()toString: ()zoneAwareStack: (...)get message: ()set message: (value)get name: ()set name: (value)get originalStack: ()set originalStack: (value)get stack: ()set stack: (value)get zoneAwareStack: ()set zoneAwareStack: (value)__proto__: Object Error: The selector "app" did not match any elements
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:24029:19) [angular]
    at DebugRenderer2.selectRootElement (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:12878:49) [angular]
    at createElement (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:9171:23) [angular]
    at createViewNodes (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:11672:44) [angular]
    at createRootView (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:11619:5) [angular]
    at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:12727:42) [angular]
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:12204:12) [angular]
    at ComponentFactory_.create (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:9591:46) [angular]
    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:3490:29) [angular]
    at ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:5024:57) [angular]
    at http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:4811:79 [angular]
    at Array.forEach (native) [angular]
    at PlatformRef_._moduleDoBootstrap (http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:4811:42) [angular]
    at http://localhost:61234/dist/vendor.js:4772:27 [angular]
consoleError @ vendor.js:100206
```

When refreshing the app manually, it loads and updates correctly.

Does anyone sees what the problem is and what I have to change? 
Thanks for help.

Comment: You may want to go through your package.json and make sure that your dependencies are on the proper (latest) versions. Specifically, zone.js to 0.8.4; typescript to 2.2.1; there may others. This may correct the problem in your other question, too.

Comment: Hi @R.Richards, thanks for the hint, but this did not solve the problem. Updated package is checked in.

Comment: Yep, you updated them all. :) The error is still the same? No change there?

Comment: Thought makes sense to update them all when I am updating it already :)! Yep, looks like same error :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused in the [boot-client.ts](https://github.com/damirkusar/AngularMeetsNetCore/blob/AngularRc4/WebApp/ClientApp/boot-client.ts) file on line 13:

```
module['hot'].dispose(() => { platform.destroy(); });
```

when removing platform.destroy(); it started to work again. So this line should look like this:

```
module['hot'].dispose(() => { });
```